# Rails precompilation error in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, production-environment

I am getting this error:

```
Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError in Main#index

Showing /etc/apache2/CrawlFish/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #15 raised:

jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min isn't precompiled
```

in config/environements/production.rb, i have added this line:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js )
```

Even after doing this, i am getting the above precompilation error. In public/assets/manifest.yml, there is no entry for jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js file. But in public/assets, there are these files generated:

```
jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min-3ef66af7d5b20341b5fceb4ad1b2755f.js
jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min-3ef66af7d5b20341b5fceb4ad1b2755f.js.gz
jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js
jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js.gz
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What does application.html.erb line 15 say?

Comment: @AnatortoiseHouse:  Line 15: <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min" %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added your jquery-ui like so jquery-ui

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
```

why are you calling it like so?

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js )
```

if it's in the asset folder, you shouldn't have any problems.

Do you have the code below on your application.rb

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

I might be way wrong but i would try that

Comment: I tried adding //=require jquery-ui and also in application.rb. Still getting the same error

Comment: maybe you should remove this line config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js )